# Sequelize count with distinct query by multiple columns

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

Is there any way in one query to have two numbers of amount unique elements from table?

Below is example what I'd like to rewrite in one query:

```
  const companyUnits: any = await models.NonCeasedCompaniesProdUnit
    .count({ distinct: true, col: 'company_id' })

  const productionUnits: any = await models.NonCeasedCompaniesProdUnit
    .count({ distinct: true, col: 'production_unit_id' })
```

I'd like to have something like:

```
const companyAndProductionUnits = {company_id: 15, production_unit_id: 7} //or [15, 7]
```

Comment: Did you try `findAll` along with `Sequelize.fn` in `attributes` and `group` option?

Comment: @Anatoly there are 4 million records and findAll() timeout about 30-40 secs, but count() is only 2 secs query

Comment: @Anatoly has a good point, try to set selected columns with attribute parameter only to counts. it should be the same as model.count then. If it is still problem, only way is raw query => 

 attributes: [
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('company_id')), 'countAlias1'],
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('production_unit_id')), 'countAlias2'],
  ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option is to try force counts as only columns to speed up a query

```js
await models.NonCeasedCompaniesProdUnit.findAll({
   attributes: [
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('company_id')), 'countAlias1'],
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('production_unit_id')), 'countAlias2'],
  ],
  distinct: true,
});
```

But this queries are always problem with sequelize, I recommend to use raw query

```js
const result = await sequelize.query(`SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT company_id) as count1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT production_unit_id) as count2
    FROM
    NonCeasedCompaniesProdUnit;`, {
  type: QueryTypes.SELECT
});
```

Comment: Thank you, second variant works find. First one has error at distinct option